# Lines Of Code in Team foundation server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, lines-of-code

I'm looking for reporting tools for TFS, I need to get Lines of Code for individual developer between 2 dates, do you think it is doable via TFS?

Comment: This is quite a hard problem, since a "line of code" could be anything from a single character change to a full inserted line.  Also, would you count a line that is added in one changeset and removed in another as two lines edited, or one, or zero?

Comment: Lines of code (sloc) are VERY misleading. A good developer may think more and write less and a sloppy one can just machine-gun code at 200 wpm and chances are the more the code - the worse it works and harder to maintain. In one occasion I had to rework a sloppy piece of code and shrunk their 10000+ lines of code to about 1500. Unless you combine *somehow* functionality delivered and divide that by sloc you'd be doing it wrong

Comment: If you can get just the code changes produced by the individual developer (not the entire source file, just the lines that were changed) you can then do a global search for line endings (usually '\n').  I have to reiterate what others have said - LoC is a mostly worthless metric.

Comment: Lets hope he hasn't "tabified" or "untabified" some pages as they will all count towards the total number of lines.  Personally, I think any value that you're looking for in number of lines, is probably completely invaluable in reality and provides a very poor metric of measuring anything other than "Number of lines altered".  If you want this to measure productivity, then I'd look for another metric.

Comment: There is a field in the analysis cube called `Total Churn` which can be filtered by person and date. Again, I'm not 100% how this is counted. Also, the issues both Dans, Sten, and discens provided are true and I agree with them about using code churn as a metric to gauge people on is quite horrendous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did it once per Management request. This may not be the perfect solution but it works. I reported LOC added for a TFS branch. I'm attaching TFS cube screenshot from old version (TFS 2008) since TFS version is missing here. I'm sure new version will be similar.

[image]

Comment: Do note that this code churn view (still present in 2015) does not distinguish between code you wrote for a feature, and code that was "created by you" as part of a branching operation or any other type of bulk movement.

Answer (score 19):

This is how I get lines of code for TFS/Visual Studio projects:

1. Open solution
2. Open window: View -> Other Windows -> Code Metrics Results
3. Run metrics: Click the icon at the top left - Calculate Code Metrics for Solution

   - Metrics collected
   - Has Lines of Code column

Comment: Does Code Metrics take into account form.Designer.cs code when calculating Lines of Code?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering about the above, [Code Metrics **does** include Windows Forms designer code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx) - _"Code generated for Windows forms is not ignored, because it is code that the developer can see and change."_

Comment: Code Metrics in VS does not support by-programmer...would need SCM like VSTS, GitHub, etc. A less-than-perfect solution is to: 1. Run metrics before the programmer's code contribution. 2. Run metrics after the programmer's code contribution. 3. Compare LoC differences.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2:

- Open Solution.
- Select "Analyze" on the toolbar.
- Click Calculate Code Metrics.
- If you have clicked on a file, it will allow you to calculate for the file, otherwise, select "For solution"

Option 3:

- Open Solution.
- In the Solution Explorer window, right click on the solution and select "Calculate code metrics"
- This again will generate the metrics in the "Code Metrics Results" window.